# How to convert jquery collection to xml string for an ajax request

Tags: jquery

I created a jquery collection that stores xml as follows:

```
var rh_request = $('<request/>')
 .attr('user_id', user_id)
 .attr('company_id', company_id)
 .attr('action', 'x');
```

I want to post it to my server via an ajax request as follows:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: mywebsiteURL,
 processData: false,
 dataType: "xml",
 data: rh_request.html(),
 success: mycallbackfunction
});
```

My problem is that the "data" parameter of the ajax call needs a string version of the xml and it seems neither Jquery's .html() or .text() function yields this. I have older code that used straight javascript to form the outgoing xml and calling the DOM .xml() function yielded a string that worked. How is this done with a jquery collection???

Comment: I edited it to make it more readable...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data: $('<div>').append(rh_request).html(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same issue and found that jQuery falls a little short when you try to use it to generate XML.  In my case, I've found it will lowercase element and attribute names and also converts 0 to empty string, depending on how you set it.  I finally resigned to using a combination of jQuery and JavaScript to produce XML.

I used the following function to produce an object, set the properties, and then call toXml() to retrieve the XML for it.

```
var $encoder = $("<div/>");
function getNewNode(nodeName) {
    return $.extend({}, {
        "nodeName": nodeName,
        attr: {},
        content: "",
        toXml: function() {
            // NOTE: change how XML is encoded here to fit your needs
            var xml = "<" + this.nodeName;
            $.each(this.attr, function(attrName, attrValue) {
                xml += " " + attrName + '="' + $encoder.text(attrValue || "").html() + '"';
            });

            return xml + ">" + this.content + "</" + this.nodeName + ">";
        }
    });
}
```

Using the above, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var request = getNewNode("request");
$.extend(request.attr, { "user_id": user_id, "company_id": company_id, "action": "x" });
var requestXml = request.toXml();
```